# Insert data from list as form id in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

quick question from me. I'm iterating through list as below and I'm tryin to "insert" one data from as list ad form id

```
<div id ="someId">    
<#list lists as list>
     <#if offerOrder.orderId??>                             
      <a href="#" onclick="someFunction();"> <img src="imagine.png"/>"</a>  
        <form id=list.data action='<@spring.url "URL"/>'>
    </form>                                     
     <#else>
    </#list>
</div>
```

I also tried `id=${list.data}`, `id="${list.data}"` etc, but it seems like it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the Java type of `list`?  Perhaps you could list some code for this type?

Comment: And what does "doesn't work" mean? Do you have an error message? BTW, since `form` is not an FTL directive, you definitely need the  `${}` there.